# Assistance with CVLine/CVPoint

Tags: opencv

In a text file, npoints3, I have coordinates of the form 1 242 2 242 3 242 ... 900 242, which is  a straight line across my image;however, the following code prints a straight line plus an additional line segment. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone assist me with why I am getting the extra line segment? Thanks in advance!

```
    IplImage* InputImg = cvLoadImage("image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    CVPoint * points  = (CvPoint*)malloc(length*sizeof(CvPoint*));
    FILE *fp;


    fp = fopen("npoints3", "r");

    for(i=1; i <= length; i++)
    {
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &(points[i].x));
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &(points[i].y));
    printf("%d  %d\n",points[i].x, points[i].y);

    }
   for(i=1; i < length; i++)
   cvLine(InputImg, points[i], points[i+1], red, 3, 1);
```

---

Thanks for your reply. In order to make sure I understood you clearly, I have posted your suggestion edits. Is the following loops what you suggested? Thanks in advance.

```
IplImage* InputImg = cvLoadImage("image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    if (!InputImg) {
       printf("Could not load Input Image");
       exit(0);
    }


    points1 = (CvPoint*)malloc(length*sizeof(CvPoint*));
           points2 = (CvPoint*)malloc(length*sizeof(CvPoint*));
    points  = (CvPoint*)malloc(length*sizeof(CvPoint*));

    fp = fopen("points", "r");

    for(i=0; i < length; i++)
    {
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &(points[i].x));
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &(points[i].y));

    }
   for(i=0; i < length; i++)
   {


       points1[i].x = points[i].x;
       points1[i].y = points[i].y;

       points2[i].x = points[i+1].x; points2[i].y = points[i+1].y;
      //   cvLine(InputImg, points1[i], points2[i], red, 3, 1);
    }

  cvSnakeImage(InputImg, points, length, alpha, beta, gamma, CV_VALUE, winni, criteria, calcGradient);

    for (i = 0; i <length-1; i++)
    {

           points1[i].x = points[i].x;
           points1[i].y = points[i].y;

           points2[i].x = points[i+1].x; points2[i].y = points[i+1].y;
             cvLine(InputImg, points1[i], points2[i], red, 3, 1);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like it might be an off-by-one error. When you call `malloc`, you are allocating enough space for an array of `length` elements. Arrays are 0-indexed -- that is, `points[0]` to `points[length-1]` are valid memory addresses, while `points[length]` is not.

At the end of your first loop, the last point you set is one element past the end of the array, and it's possible that the value gets overwritten by something by the time you try to draw the last line segment.

Try changing your first loop to be:

```
for(i=0; i < length; i++) {
    // scanf stuff here
}
```

and your second loop to:

```
for(i=0; i < length-1; i++)
    // cvLine stuff here
```